# sidemenu submenu's limit to 1 open submenu at the time with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I have a sidebar with a few submenu's. I want only one submenu to be active at the time. So if a submenu is active and you select an other submenu the first one needs to close.

this is my jquery so far:

```
$('.sb-toggle-submenu').off('click').on('click', function () {
    $submenu = $(this).parent().children('.sb-submenu');
    $(this).add($submenu).toggleClass('sb-submenu-active');

    if ($submenu.hasClass('sb-submenu-active')) {
        $submenu.slideDown(200);
    } else {
        $submenu.slideUp(200);
    }
});
```

Also have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niekdemelker/r3fSC/)

I home someone can fix this for me. I'm new to jquery an javascript but trying to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s3ag4/

```
$('.sb-toggle-submenu').off('click').on('click', function () {
    var $button = $(this);
    var $submenu = $button.next( '.sb-submenu' );

    $button.toggleClass('sb-submenu-active');

    // Detect and close other menus
    $( '.sb-submenu-active' )
        .not( $button )
        .removeClass('sb-submenu-active')
        .next( '.sb-submenu' )
        .slideUp(200);

    if ( $button.hasClass('sb-submenu-active') ) {
        $submenu.slideDown(200);
    } else {
        $submenu.slideUp(200);
    }
});
```

Comment: This one works great only there is one thing. If I open a submenu and than open an other the class `sb-submenu-active` at `<a href="#" class="sb-toggle-submenu">` stays at the first submenu.

Comment: I've updated the code above and also the fiddle. Sorry I missed that previously.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/r3fSC/8/

Here you go

```
$('.sb-toggle-submenu').off('click').on('click', function () {
    console.log($('.sb-submenu-active'));
    if ($(this).is('.sb-submenu-active')) {

        $(this).removeClass('sb-submenu-active').parent().children('.sb-submenu').slideUp(200);
    } else {

        $('.sb-submenu-active').removeClass('sb-submenu-active').parent().children('.sb-submenu').slideUp(200);
        $(this).addClass('sb-submenu-active').parent().children('.sb-submenu').slideDown(200);
    }
});
```

Comment: This seems to work properly only when i open one of the submenu's alway one stay's open. not closable

Comment: thank you for your help. Your script does wat I wanted it to do.